# Local computer and IIS Listing rdp sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I create ASP.NET application with Active RDP Sessions View.

This code successfully returns sessions while executed in Visual Studio on my local computer but when I deploy It on IIS returned List is empty and there isn't any exception thrown.

Same code in C# Console Application works fine.

Any suggestions?

```
public static List<TerminalSessionData> ListSessions(string ServerName)
{
    IntPtr server = IntPtr.Zero;
    List<TerminalSessionData> ret = new List<TerminalSessionData>();
    server = OpenServer(ServerName);

    try
    {
        IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        Int32 count = 0;
        Int32 retval = WTSEnumerateSessions(server, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref count);
        Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

        Int64 current = (int)ppSessionInfo;

        if (retval != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                current += dataSize;

                ret.Add(new TerminalSessionData(si.SessionID, si.State, si.pWinStationName));
            }

            WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseServer(server);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That is the return value (`retval`) on the server? Do you have the appropriate permissions? What happens if you temporarily run the site with Administrator privileges?

Comment: IIS is turned on with Administrator priviliges.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had to turn on Personification and enter Administrator's login/pass

Comment: Running IIS application with Administrator priviliges wasn't enough